# Is there a searchable app catalog that rank applications by power and network bandwith usage?

Tags: applications, benchmarks

I'm pretty sure I have used such a site previously, but could not find it in my bookmarks anymore.

My use case: I have some apps that I seldom use, and want to be able to quickly see how much battery and bandwith I can save by just keeping them disabled until I need to use them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to find it again - I was looking for [AppQuest](http://appquest.io/). Leaving question open in case other people know of similar sites.