# How to tame "Phone Idle" battery drain on unrooted device?

Tags: battery, battery-life, wakelock

I use `AccuBattery` and `Kaspersky Battery Life` to measure energy consumption. `Kaspersky Battery Life` shows, that all the tasks use minimal energy. `AccuBattery Pro` shows, that phone uses 5-10 mAh.
This is a fairly new, 3000 mAh battery. Phone is a `THL T9 Pro`, `Android 6.0` is installed on it.

UPDATE: I deleted all the mentioned applications and installed new one, `GSam Battery Monitor` to get detailed data:

[image: gsam screen]

There is data from the built-in usage chart too. I checked applications under Battery optimization, I found there only one, `Google Play Services`.

[image: built-in chart]

Comment: Please check battery usage in settings rather than Accubattery and kaspersky(may be they are draining the most).

Comment: @RahulGopi : Most of the usage is in "Phone - idle".

Comment: As it was mentioned earlier, I deleted these apps, because maybe these are draining the most. I checked phone's built-in stats/chart. "Phone idle" uses 1355 mAh. Phone is up 13 hours 35 minutes ago.

Comment: @beeshyams : I updated my question.

Comment: We would also need to see GSAM running for a longer period of time. Make sure you enabled extended reporting via ADB. https://plus.google.com/+GeorgeTanner/posts/gT5f7XntmEu but at first glance it appears your device is not "sleeping" properly, this is usually due to an ill-behaved application and something like WakeLock Detector would give more information as to the real cause.

Comment: @acejavelin : WakeLock Detector needs rooted device unfortunately. You are maybe right, because sometimes phone is not locked, PIN is not needed.

Comment: I use Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.32 on Ubuntu, but it doesn't find my phone.

Comment: @beeshyams : I tried it with `Chromium` yesterday, but WLD plugin couldn't find it, so I tried to use `adb devices` command, but there isn't any devices in the list.

Comment: @beeshyams : From command prompt: http://prntscr.com/ip34wi

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How to nail **Phone Idle** battery drain is the question,  but being unrooted device, it calls for some efforts. Finding the culprit apps isn't as easy as it is on rooted devices but is possible using [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) commands to enable higher privileges <sup>1</sup>

(At the time of writing, OP is working on his Linux to detect his device <sup>2</sup>. Once done with that, they can follow this answer.)

The primary cause of idle drain is *truant* [wakelock](/questions/tagged/wakelock) (s) and the answer is around how to detect apps that cause wakelocks that hurt (Wakelocks aren't bad, they are needed but not such ones). It may help to improve [doze-mode](/questions/tagged/doze-mode) performance  but more about that later.

**All methods below are working on my unrooted device running Oreo 8.0.**

## Tracking truant apps that cause battery draining wakelocks

- **Measuring Battery Drain and first level wakelock detection**

Battery usage statistics in Android, unfortunately, don't reveal much and are difficult to interpret (not withstanding the improvements in Oreo). [GSam Battery Monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gsamlabs.bbm&hl=en) is arguably the best for stock devices. One needs to enable *enhanced statistics* (Menu → more → Enable more stats) and follow the steps which are

`adb -d shell pm grant com.gsamlabs.bbm android.permission.BATTERY_STATS`<sup>**must read 3**</sup>

For the PRO version, change 'com.gsamlabs.bbm' to 'com.gsamlabs.bbm.pro' (thanks [acejavelin](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/191668/too-fast-draining-battery#comment248433_191668)).

The enhanced statistics gives better view of app usage and wakelocks as shown. Long press of *held awake* (which in OP's case is 77%) shows additional information as shown in the third screenshot.

[image]
[image]
[image]

- **Second level bad wakelock detection** (One can optionally start with this step)

Download [Wakelock Detector [LITE]](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.uzumapps.wakelockdetector.noroot&hl=en) ([XDA thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2179651)) which works without root (see this [slideshare](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1r3VlhZIZVSufZlAeICJet6QBtyAF7z06_ysl1kUKME4/edit#slide=id.g123bc9f140_169_7) for details). Two ways to run without root

- As a Chrome extension or on Chromium. OP had issues with this
- A better method is adb again

`adb shell pm grant com.uzumapps.wakelockdetector.noroot android.permission.BATTERY_STATS`

How to use (from Play Store description)

> - Charge your phone above 90% and unplug cable (or just reboot the phone)
> - Give it a time (1-2 hours) to accumulate some wakelock usage statistics
> - Open Wakelock Detector
> - Check the apps on the top, if they show very long wakelock usage time then you found the cause of your battery drain!

While 2 hours is enough to gather the information about top culprits, longer duration obviously leads to more data. During data collection, don't use the device and let it be as you would normally use the phone (with data or WiFi connected as is your normal usage). Screenshots below from my device (not under test but normal usage).

Left to right, they show Screen Wakelock, CPU Wakelock and Wakeup triggers. Check the top contributors to understand what's draining your battery.

[image]
[image]
[image]

## Eliminating the bad apps or controlling them

Once you have identified the culprits, you have three choices

- Uninstall them
- Replace them with a comparable feature app with less power consumption (assumption being they are better designed and wakelocks don't cause havoc). See [Is there a searchable app catalog that rank applications by power and network bandwith usage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/191108/131553)
- If you don't want to uninstall because you need the app, then [greenify](/questions/tagged/greenify) them!

## Taming wakelocks and improving Doze

[Greenify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify&hl=en) is a fantastic app but very powerful so needs to be used carefully. Read the [XDA thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/greenify) and [Greenify tag wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/greenify/info) for help.

I will limit to using adb to unleashing a fair part of its power to help rein in wakelocks and enhancing Doze performance.

A word about Doze, which was introduced since Marshmallow. Though it has evolved better, it has some drawbacks from battery saving point of view.

- It takes time to kick in, during which apps are active causing drain (even though screen is off)
- Doze mode is interrupted when you move the device, for example, when you are moving causing battery drain. Doze kicks in again when you are stationary with a wait period

Greenify tackles these problems with *Aggresive Doze* and *Doze on the go* (There are other apps that do this too, like [ForceDoze](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.suyashsrijan.forcedoze&hl=en), but Greenify manages both  Wakelocks and Doze).

[Instructions](https://greenify.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/749142-how-to-grant-permissions-required-by-some-features) for using adb

For different features, you need to run adb commands to grant the corresponding permission:

- Accessibility service run-on-demand:

  `adb -d shell pm grant com.oasisfeng.greenify android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS`
- Aggressive Doze on Android 7.0+ (non-root):

  `adb -d shell pm grant com.oasisfeng.greenify android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS`
- Doze on the Go:

  `adb -d shell pm grant com.oasisfeng.greenify android.permission.DUMP`
- Aggressive Doze (on device/ROM with Doze disabled):

  `adb -d shell pm grant com.oasisfeng.greenify android.permission.DUMP`
- Wake-up Tracker:

  `adb -d shell pm grant com.oasisfeng.greenify android.permission.READ_LOGS`
- Wake-up Cut-off: (Android 4.4~5.x):

  `adb -d shell pm grant com.oasisfeng.greenify android.permission.READ_LOGS`

  `adb -d shell pm grant com.oasisfeng.greenify android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS`

Background-free enforcement on Android 8+ (non-root):

```
adb -d shell pm grant com.oasisfeng.greenify android.permission.READ_APP_OPS_STATS
```

I will restrict to snapshots of settings from my device to help set it up faster after running adb commands above. I have pro version so ignore those donation settings

[image]
[image]

With those settings, even when the device is running, you will see a hibernation alert in your status bar with the app icon and in your notification panel. Clicking on that will force close and hibernate the app

[image]

You can also hibernate errant apps from Wakelock Detector by long pressing on the app

[image]

**Caution:** Be **very** careful with what you want to hibernate. Simple rule - don't hibernate apps that are critical to you. Hibernate you errant apps that are not critical

**Edit**

[BetterBatteryStats](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.asksven.betterbatterystats&hl=en)  ([XDA thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1179809)) is a very powerful tool which has been recently (end Feb 18) updated to work with Oreo and sweeter still is that escalated privileges using adb is possible

`adb -d shell pm grant com.asksven.betterbatterystats android.permission.BATTERY_STATS`

`adb -d shell pm grant com.asksven.betterbatterystats android.permission.DUMP`

On Lollipop and forward, additionally run:
`adb -d shell pm grant com.asksven.betterbatterystats android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS`

[image][image]

Happy Wakelock hunting!

- **I've done everything you suggested but it didn't help**

It's likely that a system app is causing the Wakelocks for which there isn't much you can do on an unrooted device <sup>4</sup>

---

---

- <sup>1</sup> [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/131553) and for the latest version refer to Izzy's [awesome repo](https://android.izzysoft.de/downloads). Also see this [XDA guide](https://www.xda-developers.com/install-adb-windows-macos-linux/)
- <sup>2</sup> [How do I get my device detected by ADB on Linux?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/144966/131553)
- <sup>**must read 3**</sup>:  For all adb permissions to stick,  force stop app to let the granted permission take effect. You can either do it in system "Settings → Apps → App name → Force stop", or execute this command: `adb -d shell am force-stop com.<package name of app>`
- 4
  [How to deal with (orphaned) WakeLocks?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/34969/131553)

Comment: I tried to install necessary Chrome plugin on Windows too, so I installed ADB driver on Windows too. It says, installation is OK, but Chrome plugin cannot find device. Please check screenshot: http://prntscr.com/ip2xsi

Comment: Follow this [guide](https://www.xda-developers.com/install-adb-windows-macos-linux/) or a detailed video for your OS or take help from somebody locally to get ADB  installed and correctly working. Sorry but I can't help on this remotely. It's faster to take local help

Comment: Or find somebody who has ADB running on their device and run these instructions after installing them. You can at leisure sort out the ADB problem

Comment: I found the problem in that guide. "Change the USB mode to “file transfer (MTP)” mode." I can't do this, device couldn't change method after I selected it.

Comment: Enable *Developer options* by tapping build number 7 times (from your settings likely in about phone). You will find a new item developer options in your settings. In that choose USB options > MTP.

Comment: Also enable USB debugging

Comment: This may help https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/android-wont-connect-windows-adb-fix-it-three-steps/

Answer (score 1):

if you want to just use adb to tune Doze without extra Apps.

you might be interested in https://github.com/easz/doze-tweak

and if you don't want to install extra Apps, you can profile your battery with `adb bugreport` and analyze it with Battery Historian (e.g. https://bathist.ef.lc/). After identifying bad Apps, you can disable or restrict them.