# How can I view which program wakes up my Android screen?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, screen

From time to time, I see my Android screen turns on. How can I view which program wakes up my Android screen?

I use unrooted Android 6.0 on LG4. The screen is locked.

Comment: Is your device rooted?

Comment: @beeshyams no~~

Comment: It's likely a *wakelock* created by an app to keep the screen on.  You can try solutions [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/191960/131553) to identify the truant app and uninstall that

Answer (score 1):

You should look into `dumpsys`. This works without root, using ADB.

First, enable developer mode on your phone (tap the `build number` in `settings -> information/about this phone` 7 times). Then go to `settings -> developer settings` and enable USB debugging there.

On your PC install ADB, there are many versions, [minimal ADB and fastboot](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2317790) is quite nice.

Once you got all that you can execute `adb dumpsys` on your PC within ADB to get a f**kton of increible information, from detailed battery usage to SMS history, LCD debug information, wifi radio information and a ton more. All without root, so that's pretty cool.

The `dumpsys` utility is divided into multiple modules, which you can individually access by appending their names onto the `adb dumpsys` command.

The module you should be looking at would probably be `usagestats`, so give `adb dumpsys usagestats` a run. That should show you which app was active at the time your display turns on.