# High battery usage (no wifi no apps no wireless)?

Tags: samsung, security, battery, malware, samsung-galaxy-s-10

I've noticed that I lose about 20% battery each hour while my phone is unattended and offline.  I check the battery settings and find that no apps are running.

The phone is rooted, and I'm wondering what kind of cleanup I can do in terms of searching for viruses and botnets and doing some kind of deeper inspection of battery usage?

Samsung galaxy s10+

--UPDATE--

I'd like to start looking for botnet that would survive a successful re-rom: any methods of doing so would be greatly appreciated.  I've been receiving "unauthorized network" errors while in airplane mode.  This is an intermittent issue.  I am trying to find a forum or a community where issues like this can be discussed.  I've taken comprehensive logs at various suspicious cross periods.  One of four nights I receive these issues, for example.  I vigilantly reproduce steps to be sure that each night the conditions of the phone are the same: turn all apps off, restart the phone, put it into airplane mode, turn the screen off, leave it unplugged.

Comment: You can install Better Battery Statistics and check for app /Wakelock/alarms causing the drain. That could be the first step. Also check for [Wakelocks](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/34972/131553)

Comment: [This answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/191960/131553) has more details

Comment: Thank you.  Some progress: "island" wasn't working properly and it seems turning apps on and off was causing a lot of rapid battery drain.  I'm concerned about spyware that would survive a re-rom, primarily, still.  And I still get intermittent rapid battery drain, although removing the island app temporarily has helped.  Not able to get island working properly, unfortunately.  Wondering how I would check to see if a hidden network is attached to my phone?